# AWS S3 PutObject Access denied problem in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload an image to AWS S3. This code previously worked fine (and still working for another project). This is a brand new project with a new AWS S3 bucket. I noticed they again changed a lot and maybe it's a problem.

This is the code:

```
        s3_client.upload_fileobj(
            uploaded_file,
            files_bucket_name,
            key_name,
            ExtraArgs={
                'ContentType': uploaded_file.content_type
            }
        )
```

This is the permission policy for the bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1204",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt15612",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The upload did not work until I added the "PutObject" here but it was working for another project. I don't like about this policy that PutObject is now public available.

How to make:

- all images are public available
- but only owner can upload files?

This are screenshots from AWS permissions for this bucket:

[image: Public]

[image]

Comment: Is your intent to serve public images over http? or let people browse and download from your bucket with the s3 api? If you want to serve it via http(s) - you really should use cloudfront which will do this while keeping your bucket entirely locked down. See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/

Comment: No, I'm not going to use CloudFront. I'm using S3. I want the files to be publicly accessible but the upload can be done only by the owner.

Comment: The Bucket Policy is granting anyone in the world permission to upload to your bucket and download from your bucket. You should remove that policy.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein this was the point of my question: how to allow everyone to see the files and allow an owner only to upload them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has gone as soon as I created an IAM user and granted it full access to S3. Not sure if this solution is good or not but at least it's working now.

Comment: That is the correct way to access AWS resources from code. Your code uses the permissions associated with the IAM User to access the resources in AWS. You do not necessarily need to grant it Full Access in S3 -- normally it is recommended that you grant only the access that is actually required.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yeah but before I was able to have the same permissions without IAM: I just edited the access control section and it worked. Now I couldn't achieve the same without IAM.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I didn't find the permission other than "full access to S3".

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your requirement is:

- Allow everyone to see the files
- Only allow an owner to upload them

There is a difference between "seeing the files" -- `ListObjects` allows listing of the objects in a bucket while `GetObject` allows downloading of an object.

If you want to make all objects available for download **assuming that the user knows the name of the object**, then you could use a policy like this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that this policy will not permit *viewing the contents* of the bucket.

If you wish to allow a specific IAM User permission to upload files to the bucket, then **put this policy on the IAM User** (*not* on the Bucket):

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I didn't add any policy like this one except I just did it using their visual tool.